# Unity - handle OnCollision on child's Rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

I have a GameObject, constructed from bunch of pills, where each pill is basically constructed from two spheres and a cylinder.
So the GameObject hierarchy looks something like this:

- Player (Empty GameObject)

  - Pill (Empty Game Object)

    - Sphere (3D sphere)
    - Cylinder (3D cylinder)
    - Sphere (3D sphere)

Hopefully the picture will give you guys the visual illustration of what the GameObject looks like:
[image]

Now, my goal is to have the entire GameObject - **Player** as a `Rigidbody`, while I would like to detect collision on **Pill** level. Hence I added `Rigidbody` to **Player** and `Capsule collider` to each **Pill**. However such configuration does not work - the **Pill** does not receive `OnCollisionEnter` event. I found [suggestion solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275867/unity-oncollision-event-without-rigidbody-collision), however it does not work for me either - if I set `Capsule collider` property `Is Trigger`, then **Player** does not interact with other Rigid bodies. The only solution [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876848/child-of-player-not-detecting-collision-with-rigidbody-on-other-object) so far is to add `Rigidbody` to each **Pill**, but I am concerned about performance is such scenario.

To sum up - my question is - can I have the above configuration - parent rigid body, child collider work and accept `OnCollision` events? Of course if I can have parent rigid body and a child with `Is Trigger` set will also work in case the **Player** keeps rigid body physics behavior.

Comment: Afaik the collision is always handled on `Rigidbody` level so as soon as you have a `Rigidbody` parent object the `OnCollisionXY` is fired there and not on each Collider individually. Afaik you also shouldn't nest `Rigidbody` so that's no option. But what you could try is using individual `Rigidbody` s and then attach them together by using [Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html). I guess in this case especially the [`FixedJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html) would be of your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to detect collision on **Pill** Level but retaining the same configuration one thing you can access is the [Collision ContactPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint.html).

Comment: The reason for **Pill** collision requirement is because I would like to change the **Pill** color when it collides with a specific GameObject type.